# unable to run a python script having selenium library in a crontab

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, cron

I have been trying to figure this out but couldn't find any help till now,
I am trying to run a python script having selenium chrome driver in it using crontab,
but I am getting the error no module named selenium.
although it is in a notebook I have downloaded the .py extension file and wrote the corn job:

command used in crontab:

```
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH='/Users/hiteshnettam/Downloads/chromedriver'
*/3 * * * * cd /Users/hiteshnettam/Downloads && /usr/bin/python selenium_test.py
```

---

Written below is the script to be run on crontab

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import datetime


browser1=webdriver.Chrome('/Users/hiteshnettam/Downloads/chromedriver')
browser1.get("http://www.madhavihospital.com")

element=browser1.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/center[3]/a/button")
element.click()
terms = browser1.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='name']/form/input[4]")
terms.click()
book=browser1.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='name']/form/input[5]")
book.click()
name=browser1.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='firstname']")
name.send_keys('Venkat Naidu')
mobile=browser1.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='name']/form/input[5]")
mobile.send_keys('8790121620')
Age=browser1.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='name']/form/input[6]")
Age.send_keys('75')
gender=browser1.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='name']/form/h5[4]/input[2]")
gender.click()
```

the error I am getting is: no module named selenium when I run the cronjob

Comment: Do not append pictures of code, please add the code in reproducible form.

Comment: I have edited my question with the code in the reproducible form, see if could you help me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been in the EXACT situation as you, with the combined challenges of turning a selenium GUI script on a crontab AND finding the right interpreter from Jupyter Notebook to the Terminal. Please find my steps below.

1. Download the .py file from Jupyter (as you have already done)
2. I had downloaded Jupyter through Anaconda so whenever I installed Python modules it didn't install to the default `/usr/bin/python3`, it went to a different executable. In Jupyter Notebook, run the following command:

```
import sys
sys.executable()
```

My output looked like this: `/Users/myusername/anaconda3/bin/python3.7`

This is the output you will need to use in place of `/usr/bin/python3`

3. With the crontab script, you are going to need to make it headless. Luckily with Chrome it is extremely easy. Please insert the code in the beginning of your script.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") 
browser1=webdriver.Chrome('/Users/hiteshnettam/Downloads/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
```

4. You are about halfway done, your script is headless but not good enough for crontab. To let the system know you really don't need a GUI for the script to run, you will need to modify a variable in your crontab script: `DISPLAY=:0`. This is NOT in your Python script, this is meant to go in your crontab script. I'll demonstrate at the end. None of this will actually impact functionality, the program will run the exact same. The pros to this is you won't have to be logged in for the script to run.
5. Now we can put all our information together. Note how I do not `cd` into a directory but rather refer to the files by absolute file path, this is much cleaner and is the preferred method.

Your crontab should look like this, but please replace the `sys.executable` with your own output.

```
*/3 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /Users/myusername/anaconda3/bin/python3.7 /Users/hiteshnettam/Downloads/selenium_test.py
```

Comment: Reading back on my answer I realize you only asked about the `selenium` module not being installed, so for that you're gonna wanna do the `sys.executable` and replace the `/usr/bin/python3`. I highly suggest you follow the rest of my answer as well though. I'm leaving the rest here for others with similar problems.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Rohan it worked!! I had been trying to figure this out for a week now. So nice to have a community that helps each other out.